# Swift 3 insert structure

Tags: swift, struct, swift3

Defined the structure

```
struct songStruct {
    let artist = String()
    let title = String()
    let imgUrl = String()
    let previewUrl = String()
}
```

`var songs = [songStruct]()`

> **Error**: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

`self.songs.insert(songStruct(artist: "artist", title: "title", imgUrl: "test", previewUrl: "test"), at: 0)`

Comment: Does assigning an empty (for example) title to a song make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `songStruct` does not have an init method that takes any parameters since all of the variables are being assigned a empty string.

You just need to change the definition of your properties so they aren't assigned a default value.

```
struct songStruct {
    let artist: String
    let title: String
    let imgUrl: String
    let previewUrl: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `SongStruct` is supposed to start with a capital letter.

Second of all the implicit memberwise initializer is only created if all members **don't** have default values:

```
struct SongStruct {
    let artist : String
    let title : String
    let imgUrl : String
    let previewUrl : String
}
```

Otherwise you have to add it yourself, however the properties must be declared as `var`:

```
struct SongStruct {
    var artist = "" // shorter syntax than String()
    var title = ""
    var imgUrl = ""
    var previewUrl = ""

    init(artist: String, title: String, imgUrl: String, previewUrl: String {
       self.artist = artist
       self.title = title
       self.imgUrl = imgUrl
       self.previewUrl = previewUrl
    }
}
```